# How to safely separate packet data?

Tags: java, networking

I am creating a multiplayer game and not sure how should I separate packet data.

My packet structure looks like this (it is one string): id (separator) content

And the content sometimes also has multiple separators (to send more data in one packet)

But if my game had a chat (or any other user input), user could type the separator string and break the server. How can I prevent that?

Is there any other more safe way of sending network data than PrintWriter to the socket output stream?

Comment: IRC uses `\r\n` or `\n\r` (I always get those mixed up) to mean END OF MESSAGE, you need to send something that ALWAYS without any doubt denotes the end of a message. Or find something that ALWAYS starts a message so you know when one ends.

Comment: @AlecTeal `\r\n`, always. The hardware was built to allow advancing the paper while you were retuning the carriage, but only if you returned the carriage first. If you got it wrong it would be appallingly slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 solutions:

1. Termination character - strings often end with a literal `0` (a byte of value 0) - this isn't a character so you can tell when the string ends because it reads for example `Alec0` where the `0` is a literal `0` not the letter. Because it doesn't map to a letter you KNOW that it ends the string. You could employ the same thing
2. A start character (not a good solution) suppose we start data with `0` instead (this works for streams) then you can processes `0msg0other` as `g` must be the last of `message` because `0` starts a new incoming bit of data. Then the stream ends so the last bit must be `other`
3. The most common for protocols where the messages are defined (as for games) is so common it even has a name, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value - type length value (encoding).
   Basically you say "the first 4 bytes are an integer denoted the message type" then the next 4 bytes is the length of the payload (the value) for example: `0x1` `0x4` `Alec` denotes

   - message type: 1
   - length: 4
   - data: `Alec`

Comment: Thank you, but could you please provide an example how to use Type-lenght-value in Java? I searched for it but did not get many results.

Comment: Just send an int for the type, then  an int for the data length @Ladas125